# Issue with reading a local file before loading into firebase database?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-storage

I am trying to store an image to a firebase database. I have created a simple config file and then created a hook file to retrieve the uploaded image  url from the firebase.storage. But I am getting a type error of undefined  is not an object..  Any help would be highly appreciated

Config file:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/storage';
import 'firebase/firestore';

var firebaseConfig = {
 --------

};

    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    
    const projectStorage = firebase.storage();
    const projectFirestore = firebase.firestore();
    export { projectStorage, projectFirestore, timestamp };
```

In the below code I am trying to retrieve the url of the image uploaded from firebase.storage. But getting below error and couldn't able to fix it:

[image]

```
    import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
    import { projectStorage } from "../firebase/config";
    
    
      const GetImage = (file) => {
      
      const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);
    
      useEffect(() => {
    const imageReference = projectStorage.ref(file.name);
   


    imageReference.put(file);
        const url = imageReference.getDownloadURL();
        
        setUrl(url);
      
  
  }, [file]);

  return { progress, url, error }
}

export default GetImage;
```

code for uploading image:

```
const UploadForm = () => {
  //add a local state of file
  const [file, setFiles] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  // include event object  argument in the function below as well
    // access the file that was selected for upload through event object
    //target is the import and properties called files that gives info of all file selected
    //we just add only one and first file selcted
    const pictureLoadHandler = (e) => {

      let selectedFile = e.target.files[0];
      console.log(selectedFile);

      if (selectedFile) {
        setFiles(selectedFile);
        setError(''); //erase error message on reset 

      // if the file is selected then pass the file to local storage
      // we pass selectedFile to setFilestate and eventually saved in localFileStore
    } else {
      setFiles(null);
      setError("please select a  file before upload ");
    }
  }

  return (
    <form>
      <input type="file" onChange={pictureLoadHandler} />
      <div className="output">
        {file && <div>{file.name}</div>}
        
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};
export default UploadForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite obvious. The value of `file` is `undefined`. Try to just add a check before you run your code to see if `files` has a value:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { projectStorage } from "../firebase/config";

const GetImage = (file) => {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (file) {
      const imageReference = projectStorage.ref(file.name);

      imageReference.put(file);
      const url = imageReference.getDownloadURL();

      setUrl(url);
    }
  }, [file]);

  return { progress, url, error };
};

export default GetImage;
```